# preserve YAML options from Rmd in md

Tags: yaml, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to preserve the YAML options in my rmarkdown file after knitting to markdown. Ideally it would be ignored altogether. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure front matter is preserved during `knit`ing. Can you show an example file (and the code you're using to process it)?

Comment: to clarify I mean markdown v2, the YAML

Comment: You still need to show code.

Comment: You can file a feature request here: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues

Comment: @Yihui, thanks. I will file this. Essentially, what I am looking for is a way to use Rmd files for jekyll blogging. I am packaging this here: https://github.com/bquast/hyder. I have managed to extract the title, though an API would be cool.

Main thing now would be to have the **bibliography** rendered in the markdown file.

Comment: option `preserve_yaml: true` with the current version (https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/496)

Comment: thanks Stéphane, could you write this up as an answer?